# How to update the source table in the MERGE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table `tbBroker` on my local database and a table `Agency` on linked server object "DIS".

I am trying to migrate data from local's `tbBroker` to DIS's `Agency` table

Also note that

```
tbBroker's Columns  =  Agency's Columns
BrokerCode          =  AgencyNumber
BusinesssName       =  AgencyName
City                =  City
tbSystemUser.EmailAddress = EmailAddress
```

Also, `tbBroker` has two additional columns `DISImportFlag bit` and `DISCreatTS datetime`. These two fields should be updated to `1` and `GETDATE()` whenever data is migrated (during insertion) from `tbBroker` to `Agency` table in order to determine which rows have been migrated.

I have written the following query

```
       USE [DISTemp];
       MERGE INTO
       [dbo].[Agency] AS [TARGET]
       USING
       [aginbr].[dbo].[tbBroker] AS [SOURCE]
       ON
       [TARGET].[AgencyNumber] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = [SOURCE].[BrokerCode]
       WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
       INSERT (    
       [AgencyName]
       , [Address1]
       , [Address2]
       , [PostalCode]
       , [City]
       , [Phone]
       , [EmailAddress]  
       )
       VALUES (
       [SOURCE].[BUSINESSNAME]
       , [SOURCE].[ADDRESS]
       , [SOURCE].[AddressLine2]
       , [SOURCE].[Zip]
       , [SOURCE].[City]
       , [SOURCE].[Phone]
       , [SOURCE].[Email]
       )
       UPDATE SET [SOURCE].[DISImportFlag] = 1,[SOURCE].[DISCreatTS] = GETDATE()
       WHEN MATCHED THEN
       UPDATE SET
       [TARGET].[AgencyName] = [SOURCE].[BUSINESSNAME]
        , [TARGET].[Address1] = [SOURCE].[ADDRESS]
        , [TARGET].[Address2] = [SOURCE].[AddressLine2]
        , [TARGET].[PostalCode] = [SOURCE].[Zip]
        , [TARGET].[City] = [SOURCE].[City]
        , [TARGET].[Phone] = [SOURCE].[Phone]
        , [TARGET].[EmailAddress] = [SOURCE].[Email];
```

When we execute the above query it throws error message

> A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;)

after adding the following line

```
   UPDATE SET [SOURCE].[DISImportFlag] = 1,[SOURCE].[DISCreatTS] = GETDATE()
```

---

**Edit from comments**

The source table `tbBroker` has a primary key column `BrokerID`.

I want to update in the source table those rows that were inserted into the target table, i.e. those rows that didn't exist in the target table before `MERGE`.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to change values in the `SOURCE` table as well?

Comment: Yes exactly I want to modify DISImportFlag to 1 and DISCreatTS to current date in the source table after inserting the values in agency table of DIS (a Linked server object configure on my system)... Actually I am migrating data from local to remote by DIS.

Comment: The above query works fine without  UPDATE SET [SOURCE].[DISImportFlag] = 1,[SOURCE].[DISCreatTS] = GETDATE() statement. It inserts data into Agency table.

Comment: I want to keep track of those rows which are migrated to Agency table from my local machine. That is why i have added DISImportFlag and DISCreatTS feilds on local table tbBroker. Please help me !!!

Comment: I don't think you can change some table other than `TARGET` using a single `MERGE` statement. But, you can use [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to capture the result of the `MERGE` in a helper/temporary table and then update your `SOURCE` based on that.

Comment: can u please provide code snippet... I have never implemented Merge statement

Comment: Does your `SOURCE` table have some `ID` column? Primary key? What rows in the `SOURCE` table do you want to update? Only those that were inserted into the `TARGET`, i.e. didn't exist in the `TARGET` before `MERGE`? Only those that were updated in the `TARGET`, i.e. were in the `TARGET` already? Both? If both, then it means that all rows in `SOURCE` should be updated. Edit your question and add these details to the question.

Comment: Yes... "BrokerID"  is Primary key column in tbBroker(source table)

Comment: your answer to second question is Only those that were inserted into the TARGET, i.e. didn't exist in the TARGET before MERGE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can change some table other than `TARGET` using a single `MERGE` statement. But, you can use [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to capture the result of the `MERGE` in a helper/temporary table and then update your `SOURCE` based on that.

You said that you want to update only those rows that were inserted into the Target, i.e. those that didn't exist in the Target before `MERGE`.

Output `IDs` of inserted rows into the temporary table and then use it to update the `Source` table.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(
    BrokerID int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Broker] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    BrokerID ASC
));

INSERT INTO #Temp (BrokerID)
SELECT TableChanges.BrokerID
FROM
    (
        MERGE INTO [dbo].[Agency] AS [TARGET]
        USING [aginbr].[dbo].[tbBroker] AS [SOURCE]
        ON [TARGET].[AgencyNumber] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = [SOURCE].[BrokerCode]
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT
        (
            [AgencyName]
            , [Address1]
            , [Address2]
            , [PostalCode]
            , [City]
            , [Phone]
            , [EmailAddress]
        )
        VALUES
        (
            [SOURCE].[BUSINESSNAME]
            , [SOURCE].[ADDRESS]
            , [SOURCE].[AddressLine2]
            , [SOURCE].[Zip]
            , [SOURCE].[City]
            , [SOURCE].[Phone]
            , [SOURCE].[Email]
        )
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
            [TARGET].[AgencyName] = [SOURCE].[BUSINESSNAME]
            , [TARGET].[Address1] = [SOURCE].[ADDRESS]
            , [TARGET].[Address2] = [SOURCE].[AddressLine2]
            , [TARGET].[PostalCode] = [SOURCE].[Zip]
            , [TARGET].[City] = [SOURCE].[City]
            , [TARGET].[Phone] = [SOURCE].[Phone]
            , [TARGET].[EmailAddress] = [SOURCE].[Email]
        OUTPUT $action, [SOURCE].BrokerID
    ) AS TableChanges (MergeAction, BrokerID)
WHERE TableChanges.MergeAction = 'INSERT'
;

UPDATE [aginbr].[dbo].[tbBroker]
SET
    [DISImportFlag] = 1
    ,[DISCreatTS] = GETDATE()
WHERE
    BrokerID IN 
    (
        SELECT T.BrokerID FROM #Temp AS T
    )
;

DROP TABLE #Temp;
```

Obviously, wrap this whole thing in a transaction and `TRY ... CATCH` and add appropriate error handling.

Comment: Great answer. To the OP, always be cautious with MERGE and production tables. If you expect the code to run at the same time by multiple people, then you have to add HOLDLOCK. We also noticed it causes more lock escalations at the table level which can impact other queries running on the source and especially target entities

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I am getting "A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement." when trying to do this.

Comment: Sorry, @domenicr, it's been a long time ago.You'd better ask a new question.